# Vertical bar in a math mode inside tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode, symbols

I cannot get the | line to appear in a fraction in a tabular. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}\vspace{1cm}
        \begin{tabular}{c c}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Form} & \textbf{Value}\\
            \midrule
            $\frac{ Pr( \textsc{like-ChicagoBear(A) | Live-in-illinois(A)} ) }{Pr(\textsc{Like-ChicagoBear(A) | Not-live-in-illinois})}$ & 17.8\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{\color{Green} Location Examples}
        \label{table:location_examples}
    \end{center}\vspace{1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because it is inside of a `\textsc{}` argument (which takes it momentarily out of math mode).

Comment: If you want to post an answer I can approve and close this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Most importantly, place the text material before and after the vertical bar inside separate \textsc{...} directives.
- Instead of `\frac`, use `\dfrac` (requires the `amsmath` package). The terms in the numerator and denominator will look much less cramped.
- Consider using `\big`-sized outer parentheses in both the numerator and denominator.
- Instead of inputting a vertical bar, i.e., `|`, directly, I suggest you use `\mid`. Doing so will give you better spacing when used in display-style or text-style math mode -- as is the case when using `\dfrac`. If you use `big`-sized outer parentheses, you may want to use `\bigm|` to get a `big`-sized version of `\mid`.
- Last but not least, write `\Pr` instead of just `Pr` -- "Pr" is a "math operator" and should be typeset in upright letters, not in math-italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
  \textbf{Form} & \textbf{Value}\\
  \midrule
  $\dfrac{ \Pr \bigl( \textsc{Like-ChicagoBear(A)} \bigm| 
                      \textsc{Live-in-Illinois(A)} \bigr)}
         { \Pr \bigl( \textsc{Like-ChicagoBear(A)} \bigm| 
                      \textsc{Not-Live-in-Illinois}\bigr)}$ 
  & 17.8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{\color{Green} Location Examples}
\label{table:location_examples}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why my table is so crammed. After adding your changes it looks readable now :D

Comment: My cells are crammed, anyway to increase the height and vertically centre the text?

Comment: @codehitman - Do all of the "crammed" cells contain fractions? If so, `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` will provide much relief. Fractions, large sums, and integral symbols should be centered by default. Are you maybe asking about how to go about increasing the vertical separation between rows?

Comment: Instead of `\mid`, since you are using `\bigl(`, you can use `\bigm|`.

Comment: @Manuel - Many thanks for this good suggestion. I've updated my answer accordingly.